# Time & hour formatting issue when creating Excel report with Go

Tags: excel, go

I'm trying to generate an Excel sheet based on a certain table from database. The library I'm using for Excel generation is [excelize](https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize).

This is the table:
[image]

This is the full code:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

const (
    host     = "localhost"
    port     = 2019
    user     = "postgres"
    password = "dbadmin"
    dbname   = "oc-indo-dev"
)

type M map[string]interface{}

func DBconnect() *sql.DB {
    psqlInfo := fmt.Sprintf("host=%s port=%d user=%s "+
        "password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        host, port, user, password, dbname)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", psqlInfo)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db
}

/*
type NullString struct {
    sql.NullString
}
*/

type NullTime struct {
    sql.NullString
}

/*
func (ns *NullString) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !ns.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }
    return json.Marshal(ns.String)
}
*/

type NullDate struct {
    sql.NullString
}

func (nd *NullDate) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !nd.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }

    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, nd.String)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return json.Marshal(t.Format("02-01-2006"))
}

func (nt *NullTime) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if !nt.Valid {
        return []byte("null"), nil
    }

    //t, err := time.Parse("3 04 PM", nt.String)
    //t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "0000-01-01T16:29:02+07:00")
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, nt.String)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return json.Marshal(t.Format("15:04:05"))
}

type LogItem struct {
    UserId      string   `form:"id" json:"id"`
    UserName    string   `form:"name" json:"name"`
    UserDate    NullDate `form:"date" json:"date"`
    CheckinTime NullTime `form:"checkintime" json:"checkintime"`
    //CheckinLocation  NullString `form:"checkinlocation" json:"checkinlocation"`
    CheckoutTime NullTime `form:"checkouttime" json:"checkouttime"`
    //CheckoutLocation NullString `form:"checkoutlocation" json:"checkoutlocation"`
    CheckinDistance  sql.NullInt64 `form:"checkindistance" json:"checkindistance"`
    CheckoutDistance sql.NullInt64 `form:"checkoutdistance" json:"checkoutdistance"`
}

func main() {

    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"*"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "OPTIONS"})

    router := mux.NewRouter()
    router.HandleFunc("/report", doCreateReport).Methods("GET")
    http.Handle("/", router)
    fmt.Println("Connected to port 1234...")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":1234", handlers.CORS(originsOk, headersOk, methodsOk)(router)))
}

func doCreateReport(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var sqlQuery string
    var arrLogItem []LogItem
    var logItem LogItem

    sqlQuery = "SELECT oc_log.userid, oc_user.username, oc_log.userdate, oc_log.checkin_time, oc_log.checkin_distance, oc_log.checkout_time, oc_log.checkout_distance FROM oc_log join oc_user on oc_user.userid = oc_log.userid;"
    db := DBconnect()
    defer db.Close()

    rows, err := db.Query(sqlQuery)
    if err != nil {
        log.Print(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rows.Scan(&logItem.UserId, &logItem.UserName, &logItem.UserDate, &logItem.CheckinTime, &logItem.CheckinDistance, &logItem.CheckoutTime, &logItem.CheckoutDistance); err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err.Error())

        } else {
            arrLogItem = append(arrLogItem, logItem)
        }
    }

    xlsx := excelize.NewFile()
    sheet1Name := "Sheet One"
    xlsx.SetSheetName(xlsx.GetSheetName(1), sheet1Name)

    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "A1", "User ID")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "B1", "Name")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "C1", "Date")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "D1", "Checkin hour")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "E1", "Checkin distance")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "F1", "Checkout hour")
    xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, "G1", "Checkout distance")

    for idx, elem := range arrLogItem {
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("A%d", idx+2), elem.UserId)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("B%d", idx+2), elem.UserName)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("C%d", idx+2), elem.UserDate)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("D%d", idx+2), elem.CheckinTime)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("E%d", idx+2), elem.CheckinDistance)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("F%d", idx+2), elem.CheckoutTime)
        xlsx.SetCellValue(sheet1Name, fmt.Sprintf("G%d", idx+2), elem.CheckoutDistance)
    }

    err = xlsx.SaveAs("./report.xlsx")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(arrLogItem)
}
```

The tabel converted into JSON looks OK:

```
 {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Tester 02",
        "date": "07-10-2019",
        "checkintime": "12:41:40",
        "checkouttime": null,
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Tester 02",
        "date": "08-10-2019",
        "checkintime": "17:59:17",
        "checkouttime": null,
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "9",
        "name": "Tester 02",
        "date": "11-10-2019",
        "checkintime": "12:17:53",
        "checkouttime": null,
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Jack",
        "date": "17-10-2019",
        "checkintime": null,
        "checkouttime": "15:01:30",
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 4,
            "Valid": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Jack",
        "date": "17-10-2019",
        "checkintime": null,
        "checkouttime": "15:02:05",
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 4,
            "Valid": true
        }
    },
    {
        "id": "10",
        "name": "Jack",
        "date": "17-10-2019",
        "checkintime": "15:03:11",
        "checkouttime": null,
        "checkindistance": {
            "Int64": 4,
            "Valid": true
        },
        "checkoutdistance": {
            "Int64": 0,
            "Valid": false
        }
    },
```

And now, the Excel file created by the code:
[image]

Obviously, there are formatting issues. For example in the JSON you see

> "date": "25-09-2019",
>           "checkintime": "14:56:39",
>           "checkouttime": "15:52:22",

But it's displayed on Excel as:

> {{2019-09-25T00:00:00Z true}} {{0000-01-01T14:56:39+07:00 true}}  {0
>   true} {{0000-01-01T15:52:22+07:00 true}}

How to properly format the hour/time on Excel, then?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with excelize, but using your JSON as a source, after correcting for the presence of multiple root elements in your snippet, a VBA or Power Query Excel JSON parser can extract the data properly.  So I suspect the issue is not one of how Excel **formats** the result, but rather how **excelize** is extracting the data from the JSON to Excel.

Comment: "How to properly format the hour/time?" By passing properly formatted strings (or any other supported type) to SetCellValue instead of your custom null types.